# Impossible to create content or edit image styles after Backup/Restore

Tags: 7, backups

I'm having difficulties with a website that's running 7.14.
I did a backup with backup & migrate, installed a new instance of Drupal (7.40), installed the latest versions of all the modules used in the original website
I then restore the database (using backup & migrate also) but I can't create content or create/edit image styles. Whenever I try, I get this error message:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Any ideas on what causes this error? Or how to solve it?

Comment: how you take backup

Comment: I have solved similar problem by running database updates. Please see your status report and dblogs as well. If you are using drush :

drush updatedb

Comment: did you run update.php

Comment: `yourwebsite.com/update.php`

Comment: I ran update.php and still had the problem

Comment: I think it's a backwards compatiblity problem. Some modules used on the 'production' go from old version to major version updates and that's where the problems come from. I'll try and update the modules one after the other till i find the one that breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

[How To Update Drupal Core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290)

Follow these instructions:

1. Make a backup of your Drupal instance (database).
2. Download the latest release of your current Drupal version.
3. Extract the [tar ball or zip] Drupal package.
4. Set your site on maintenance mode
5. Delete all the files & folders inside your original Drupal instance
   except for /sites and its sub-folders. This assumes that all of your
   custom work - including themes - is in the recommended spot - the
   /sites folder tree. If you have made custom changes elsewhere you
   will need to either preserve them or plan to replace them later.
6. Copy all the folders and files except /sites from inside the
   extracted Drupal package [tar ball or zip package] into your
   original Drupal instance location.
7. Some updates do not include changes to setting.php and some do. See
   There is a way - Comment below for more on this. If the update
   release includes changes to settings.php you will need to replace
   your old settings.php in .../sites/default/ with the new one, and
   then edit the site-specific entries (eg database name, user, and
   password) in the setting file.
8. If you have modified files such as .htaccess or robots.txt re-apply
   those changes to the new files.
9. If you have a favicon.ico file that was deleted replace it too
10. Login to your site as administrator or as user no 1
11. Run update.php by navigating to
     http://...yourdrupalsitename/update.php and follow the process to
     update your Drupal instance
12. Disable maintenance mode